# Redux set state only if state is different

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I am using Redux for state management, but I encountered a problem. My issue is I like to set state only if state is different. Let me clarify my problem through my code.

```
// MyComponent.jsx
 const [query, setQuery] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
    if(query.length) {
      let {search, cancel} = searchContent(query);

      search.then(res => 
        setSearchResult(res.data)
        ).catch(e => {
          if(axios.isCancel(e)){
            return;
          }
        })
      return () => cancel();
    }else{
      setSearchResult(null);
    }
  }, [query, setSearchResult])
```

Above is my component that is supposed to set search state.

```
// action.js
export const SET_SEARCH_RESULT = 'SET_SEARCH_RESULT';

export const setSearchResult = (val) => ({
  type: SET_SEARCH_RESULT,
  searchResult: val,
});

//reducer.js
import { SET_SEARCH_RESULT } from './article.action';

const INITIAL_STATE = {
  searchResult: null
}

const articleReducer = (state=INITIAL_STATE, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SET_SEARCH_RESULT:
    return {
      ...state,
      searchResult: action.searchResult
    }
    default:
      return state
  }
}
```

I am able to set state using redux and it works fine. However, my problem is even though initial state is null, when *useEffect* function runs initially my state sets to null.

My question is how can I use redux so that only it runs if state is different.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can conditionally check in your articleReducer, However that shouldn't make a difference since when you use a selector it will not cause a re-render is same value is accessed unless you change the reference

Comment: Thanks for quick answer. I actually do not want to run redux if it sets to same value. Initial 'searchResult' is null, but in useEffect it also set searchResult to null. How can I prevent this behavior?